# How to introduce a no argument constructor in case we have final field which are not initialized while using JAXB?

Tags: java, jaxb, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I am trying to use JAXB to serialize my java objects to XML. In order to use JAXB the class that has to be serialized must have a no argument constructor. But my problem is all the feilds are  final so I cannot do this. If I set the class fields to null like

```
private final double Offset;
public MyNoArgumentConstructor()
   {
this.Offset = null; 
}
```

It would throw a null pointer exception . Any Idea on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare as a `Double` object instead of `double` primitive you won't get an NPE with that code.